# How to use distinct keyword for single column when selecting multiple columns in a Select Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I want to use `distinct` keyword for a single column **[BLC.Container_No]** in a `SELECT` statement which is having multiple columns.

My query:

```
SELECT BLD.VV_CODE,
       V.Vessel_name,
       BLD.Arrival_date,
       ISNULL(IGM.VIR_NO, 'NULL') AS VIR_NO,
       ISNULL(BLD.TERMINAL_CODE, 'NULL') AS TERMINAL_CODE,
       BLD.BL_NO,
       ISNULL(BLD.Parent_BL, 'NULL') AS Parent_BL,
       BLD.Consignee_Description,
       DO.DO_Issue_Date,
       CA.CAgent_Name,
       BLC.Container_No,
       CS.Container_Size_Description
FROM Vessel V,
     IGM,
     BL_DATA BLD,
     CAgent CA,
     Delivery_Order DO,
     BL_Container BLC,
     Container_Size CS
WHERE V.Vessel_code = SUBSTRING(BLD.VV_CODE, 1, 3)
  AND BLD.VV_CODE = IGM.VV_CODE
  AND DO.CAgent_Code = CA.CAgent_Code
  AND BLD.BL_NO = BLC.BL_NO
  AND BLC.Container_Size_Code = CS.Container_Size_Code;
```

Comment: You can't really do that directly.  If you want only distinct `Container_No` values, then you need some logic for what the values of all the other columns should be.  Add some sample input and output data to make your requirements clear.

Comment: Come join 2018! 1989 was almost 30 years ago now: [Bad habits to kick: using old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. How would SQL know which BLC.Container_NO  you want?You have to tell sql which one of those you want. You can use this one.

```
With cte as(
SELECT BLD.VV_CODE,
       V.Vessel_name,
       BLD.Arrival_date,
       ISNULL(IGM.VIR_NO, 'NULL') AS VIR_NO,
       ISNULL(BLD.TERMINAL_CODE, 'NULL') AS TERMINAL_CODE,
       BLD.BL_NO,
       ISNULL(BLD.Parent_BL, 'NULL') AS Parent_BL,
       BLD.Consignee_Description,
       DO.DO_Issue_Date,
       CA.CAgent_Name,
       BLC.Container_No,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BLD.VV_CODE ORDER BY BLC.Container_No asc) AS row_num
       ,CS.Container_Size_Description
FROM Vessel V,
     IGM,
     BL_DATA BLD,
     CAgent CA,
     Delivery_Order DO,
     BL_Container BLC,
     Container_Size CS
WHERE V.Vessel_code = SUBSTRING(BLD.VV_CODE, 1, 3)
  AND BLD.VV_CODE = IGM.VV_CODE
  AND DO.CAgent_Code = CA.CAgent_Code
  AND BLD.BL_NO = BLC.BL_NO
  AND BLC.Container_Size_Code = CS.Container_Size_Code)

  SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: At least get rid of those implicit joins... :)

Comment: how come you know that it will be PARTITION BY BLD.VV_CODE ?where it is written ?

Answer (score 0):

you just cant.. unless you group columns.. then you can specify grouping functions like `count(distinct field1)` or `sum(distinct field2)` etc.